# problem in numbering equations using \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

Tags: numbering

I'm writing an article where the first two sections have no subsection, but third one has two subsections. 1st section has 2 equations, 2nd has 3 equations and third one has 2+2 equations.

When I use `\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}`, I get the following numbering for the equations:

**1st section**

1.0.1

1.0.2

**2nd section**

2.0.3

2.0.4

2.0.5

**3rd section**

**1st subsection**

3.1.1

3.1.2

**2nd subsection**

3.2.1

3.2.2

But is there any way to get the equation number of 2nd section as

**2nd section**

2.0.1

2.0.2

2.0.3

?

Comment: This is normal behaviour. What do you expect? Kindly add your code to the question in form of a MWE.

Comment: It looks like you did not have a `\subsection` command so far, such that the subsection number is `0`

Comment: Unless you have a whole avalanche of equations in every `section` and thus need to provide finer control of the numbering, I think there's absolutely nothing to be gained from specifying `\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}`. Instead, go with `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`. That way, the equation numbers won't be too long and unwieldy.

Comment: @Mico: I have a similar problem in a document with exercises. The good reason for numbering within subsections (or withing exercises in my case) is that you get more stable numbers. Think of adding an equation to one subsection/exercise. Then labels of all equations in subsequent subsections/exercises change. That means that you have to update external sources that reference those equations as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing things, with the help of the `changcntr` package.
First, if you do not want to display `0`for non-existent subsections — i.e. if there is no subsection at one point, display only the section number+the equation number:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
\renewcommand\theequation{\ifnumgreater{\value{subsection}}{0}{\thesubsection.}{\thesection.}\arabic{equation}}%

\begin{document}

\section{A First Section}
\begin{equation}
a = b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a + c = b + c
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a × c = b × c
\end{equation}

\section{A Second Section}
\begin{equation}
a = b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a + c = b + c
\end{equation}

\section{A Third Section}

An extra equation :
\begin{equation}\
  \ln a = \ln b
\end{equation}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{equation}
a = b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a + c = b + c
\end{equation}

\subsection{Second subsection}
\begin{equation}
a = b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a + c = b + c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the `0` to be displayed, remove from the preamble `\renewcommand\theequation{…}` and `\usepackage{etoolbox}`, and replace `counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}` with the non-starred version.

[image]